# Run application in firefox browser without menubar, toolbar, address bar?

Tags: javascript

My requirement is to run the .net web application in firefox portable browser(Mozilla Firefox ESR 31.1.0) without Menubar, Toolbar and Bookmarks as like popup window. Please. Look at my below code, it does my requirement but parent window not closing. How do I achieve that?

The following code works in other major browsers(IE and Chrome). Kindly do the needful.

### Code Snippet:-

```
if (Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Id"]) == "a")
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "Script", "<script language='javascript'>window.opener.close();</script>", false);
else
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "Script", "<script language='javascript'>NewWin=window.open('Default. aspx?Id=a',null,'width=' + screen.width + ', height=' + screen.height + ', top=0, left=0, resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes ,location=no,directories=no,status=no');window.ope n('','_self','');</script>", false);
```

Comment: Why would the parent window be closing? How is that related to running a full screen application?

Comment: If you haven't programmatically opened a window, browser security in general won't let you programmatically close it, certainly not without a popup warning to the user.